# How to set TIMESTAMP default value to 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysql-5.7, timezone, default-value

How can I set the default value for a TIMESTAMP column to be exactly 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC without changing `time_zone`?

I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (`ts` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CONVERT_TZ(
    '1970-01-01 00:00:01', '+00.00', @@session.time_zone));
```

but got a syntax error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 00:00:01', '+00.00', @@session.time_zone))` at line 1

Is there any way to do this without creating a TRIGGER?  If not, how would I do it with a TRIGGER?

Comment: Defaults cannot be dependent on external circumstances (the results from a query, session parameters, etc), they have to be constants. Perhaps you'd be better off with the ALLBALLS special timestamp value (`'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`) which is not UTC dependent. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister:  If I try `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` as the default value I get "ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'ts'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT after clarification:**

I'm afraid you can't deal with it the way you intend.
You have to find another way, like for example defaulting to `NULL` and selecting via

```
SELECT COALESCE(ts, CONVERT_TZ( '1970-01-01 00:00:01', '+00.00', @@session.time_zone)) AS ts, ...
```

Or just use `datetime` and store the time_zone in a separate column. It depends on your requirements. But there's no way you can make it work like you want to, not even with triggers.

**Original answer:**

You can't use any functions in a table definition.

What you're trying to do is unnecessary anyway. May I quote the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store. If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for conversion in both directions. The current time zone is available as the value of the time_zone system variable.

If you are querying a database across different timezones, and need the date/time to reflect individual users settings, use `timestamp`. If you need consistency regardless of timezone, use `datetime`.

Comment: I need the date/time to reflect session timezone settings, so I need to use TIMESTAMP.  I need the default to be the moment in time described by 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC (but displayed to the client according to the current value of `@@session.time_zone`).  So this does not answer my question.

Comment: Yes, it does. It means, that all you have to do is `create table foo(bar timestamp default '1970-01-01 00:00:01');` Nothing else. Is there something unclear in the text I quoted?

Comment: The string literal `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` is not the same time as 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC unless `@@session.time_zone` is UTC—it is 1970-01-01 00:00:01 in the current time zone.  That is not what I want.  If the current time zone is east of +00:00 then `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` is actually in 1969 UTC, which is outside the valid range of the TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the problem. I'm afraid you can't deal with it the way you intend. You have to find another way, like for example defaulting to `NULL` and selecting via `SELECT COALESCE(ts, CONVERT_TZ(
    '1970-01-01 00:00:01', '+00.00', @@session.time_zone)) AS ts, ...` or whatever. Or just use datetime and store the time_zone in a separate column, I don't know your requirements. But there's no way you can make it work like you want to.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  If you (or someone else) posts an answer saying "that's not possible" and mentions the alternatives you suggested (and maybe a way to do it with triggers, if that's possible), I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @RichardHansen Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP does exactly what you are asking for, if I understood it correctly:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (`ts` DATETIME DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01');
```

Comment: I want to record the moment of time that is described by 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC.  If I switched to DATETIME then I would have to modify some code to change how I process the value stored in the column.  I'd like to avoid that if possible.  What I asked seems like something that should be possible if not easy to do, but maybe it's not possible.